# EthereumJ within osgi

Tags: dapp-development

I am trying ito integrate EthereumJ within a OSGi based application. Has anyone succeeded doing so? I can't seem to get the `dependencies/gradle.build` right. Other that that, is it possible to have a node running as seperate process and remotely access this node via an API (Rest)?

thx

Answer (score 1):

I had build a small plugin for eclipse, there I used maven to resolve the dependencies and then I stuff all the jars in a lib directory and made it available.

To access the blockchain and smart contracts take a look at https://github.com/adridadou/eth-contract-api it provides an api to access native via ethereumJ or per rpc via web3j.

I use it to write my Junit tests for the smart contracts.

An example to use it is here: https://github.com/UrsZeidler/smart-contract-examples/blob/master/javaExample/README.md

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I looked at your examples and they seem promising. My problem is that i am not able to actually run any external dependency  like EthereumJ within the OSGi framework. I can compile (using gradle) , but running always gives me some errors about not found classes.

Comment: What OSGi container you use?

Comment: I use apache felix. Currently i am trying to utilize the  run-osgi gradle plugin (see [link](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.athaydes.osgi-run) ), but no sucess yet. I am struggling with the numerous dependencies..

Comment: seems that i made some small progress, at least i don´t see hundreds of exceptions anymore when runnig :)

Comment: As said the simples way would be grabbing all the ethereumJ jars (with the dependencies) put them in a folder in your bundle and refer them in the Manifest as Bundle-ClassPath. But if it works with gradle you are better off.